# Data capturing from webpage "POP UP" tables using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
Source = "https://otcportal.tax.ok.gov/gpx/gp_PublicSearchPUNbyLegal.php"
objIE.Navigate Source

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set ele2 = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each opt In ele2
    If opt.getAttribute("value") = "PUN" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
Set ele3 = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each opt In ele3
    If opt.getAttribute("name") = "OTCtxtPUN" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Value = "073-055988-0-0000"
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each opt In ele
    If opt.getAttribute("name") = "submit" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
Set ele5 = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each opt In ele5
    If opt.getAttribute("class") = "showDetails" Then
        opt.Focus
        opt.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next opt

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"))
i=i+1    
loop

End Sub
```

**pop up table**

Now at the end of running this code, I am getting a Pop-up table containing some data in different tabs. How to capture all the data from each tab in excel?

Comment: The top of your code is missing. What function does the outer loop that increments _i_ serve?

Comment: If this website is not public then we also need to see the relevant html. For the code you have shown you might consider the re-write  https://pastebin.com/KvxABicD . We have no idea what the pop-ups look like btw. I cannot access website in UK.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, for this website I am using a VPN(a US IP). I have not given the first part of my code actually. It is a bit lengthy. Your part of code thinking is right but I am getting a run time error 424 for this. After inputting the PUN number that I mention in the program, you get a PUN link. If you click in that we will have a pop-up data table. I need to scrap that data especially the API mentioned in the PUN Details

Comment: 424 for which line? And does that error disappear if you step through executing code line by line with F8?

Comment: It is coming from line 7 & I have debagged the program using F8

Comment: what is the code on that line? Also, does the error go away if you leave a little pause before executing that line?

Comment: objIE.document.querySelector("input [value=PUN]").Click  I have used application.wait comment too, the reason is not the pause. But I can resolve that in my code. Can you please help me to capture the pop-up data that is coming in the next page in  any excel

Comment: Either the selector is wrong (can't tell without seeing HTML) or it is a timing issue - if a timing issue then error should go away with the a pause placed before that line.

Comment: Ok. I can solve up to that.. need to capture the table pop-uping in the next page

Comment: I don’t think anyone can help you with that as we can’t see it and have no idea what it’s title, handle, html is like

Comment: Every time you click on a PUN number the white popup shows up, and the html code is modified at the end of the file... Do a right click and inspect, and select different PUN numbers, so you can see the website html code change, this is called dynamic html, so you must simulate the clicks on PUNs, and then parse the html code each time looking for a table rows "tr" and columns "td". Each tab is in a different  tags : div id="tabs-1", div id="tabs-2", up to tab-6. I'm just about to do that in python, which I like a bit better than vb. But they should both work.